# F2-F1 Conundrum

Tags: student-visa, f2-visa

I had earlier applied for an F2 visa for my spouse and she is waiting to go for interview in November. About a week ago, after being refused last year, she has received funding in the Agric department in my school for Spring 2023. Our problem is whether we should proceed with the F2 and change status later or cancel the F2 application and go with F1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since she's going to be a student on her own, she should be getting her own F1 visa. Her school can help her with all the paperwork.

Each being on F1 independently can help a lot. Consider if you for any reason quit or drop out of your studies - if your spouse has their own F1 status, you can switch to F2 and stay. If your spouse is your dependent you'd both need to leave.